# Cordova-iOS:extras is empty at receiving push notification with urban airship

Tags: ios, push-notification, cordova-3, urbanairship.com

I am developing a cordova(3.4.0) app both for Android and iOS. I am integrating urban airship push notification. I am sending push message and url in extras from server. In android, push message and extras are coming properly but I am receiving empty extras in iOS. I am following urban airship phonegap document http://docs.urbanairship.com/build/phonegap.html

Code for receive push and extras

```
 var handleIncomingPush = function(event) {
                  if(event.message) {
                    console.log("Incoming push: " + event.message)
                    //alert(event.message);
                  } else {
                    console.log("No incoming message")
                  }
                  if(event.extras.url) {
                    console.log("URL")
                    window.open(event.extras.url,'_blank','location=no,closebuttoncaption=Done,toolbar=yes,toolbarposition=bottom');
                  }
                }
```

Playload is

```
 Payload: {"aliases":["alias_xssh"],"aps":{"badge":"+1","extra":{"url":"http:\/\/jhe.com\/task.php?action=daily&username=ins-mobile&date=2014-05-12"},"alert":"This is subject"}
```

When receiving in xcode the log is

```
aps =     {
    alert = "This is subject";
    badge = 16;
    extra =         {
        url = "http://jhe.com/task.php?action=daily&username=ins-mobile&date=2014-05-12";
    };
};

2014-05-13 20:00:36.072 ListCreator[974:60b] {"message":"This is subject","extras":{}}
```

Problem is in last line. `extras:{} is empty`. This same code running properly in Android but not getting extras in iOS.

Any suggestion will highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Payload should be something like

```
Payload: "aps": {"alert": "This is subject", "badge": 1}, "url": "http:\/\/jhe.com\/task.php?action=daily&username=ins-mobile&date=2014-05-12"

console.log(event.extras.url);
```

Hope this helps